# Build complex mustache or handlebar with complex array

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have the following json ( but with 100 pages) :

```
{
  "data":{
     "page":{["x":1,"y":2],["x":1,"y":2],["x":1,"y":2]},
     "page":{["x":2,"y":2],["x":1,"y":2],["x":1,"y":2]},
     "page":{["x":3,"y":2],["x":1,"y":2],["x":1,"y":2]},
  }
}
```

How can I print the following HTML with a mustache or handlebars  :

I tried to do #page then /#page and /data and #data inside but it does not work

I would like to print after mustache the following HTML

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div>x value here></div>
        <div>y value here></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: None of that is even valid syntax. Please edit your question. Also, it's unclear why you need a templating engine for something this simple. Why do you need mustache?

Comment: because i have 100 pages

Comment: @Tuz your json format is wrong. it should be something like { data: {vals: [ { x: 1, y: 2} ] } }

Comment: @Tuz ...um, and? What does that have to do with anything I said?

Comment: Completely unrelated to your answer, but you shouldn't use tag openers and closers like `>` in HTML, unless you are opening or closing an HTML tag. It's bad practice and will make a lot of IDEs and editors complain at you.

Comment: When you say "How can I print the following HTML with a mustache or handlebars", are you literally trying to draw a mustache on the page or are you trying to do _something_ using the templating framework [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)?

Answer (score 1):

try this. syntactically looks good to me. should work in most cases. I have tampered with your data a little in which I felt was correct.

```
const vals  = {
  "data":{
    "page1":[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2}],
    "page2":[{"x":2,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2}],
    "page3":[{"x":3,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":2}],
  }
};
const { data } = vals; 
Mustache.render((`
<div class="page">
${Object.keys(data).map(v =>
  `<div class="data">
      ${data[v].map((t) => `<div>{{t.x}}</div><div>{{t.y}}</div>`)}
  </div>
</div>`)}`, vals);
```

Comment: @klveky  how can i do that from the javascript code because my template is in html file

Comment: @tuz I agree that part. but you can write this entire text which is in the render as a text and it should be able to render the corresponding html markup,. I have worked with ejs and handlebars which work similarly. But check how mustache.js works as it's implementation might be different